# How to use RowFilter.dateFilter on JTable if it contains Strings

Tags: java, swing, date, jtable, rowfilter

I want to use a RowFilter.dateFilter on a JTable, but my Table has only Strings formatted like this "yyyy-MM-dd". If it's not possible to filter my JTable through a dateFilter, how can I solve this problem?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

You should be storing Date objects in your TableModel, not a String representation of the date. Then you can use a renderer to format the date however you want it displayed. See [Table Format Renderers](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/11/table-format-renderers/) for an example renderer.

Now you can use the DateFilter the way it was designed to be used.